# Change hover/active background color of Find actions buttons in Visual Studio Code

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

In the `Updated Find actions` section of the [Visual Studio Code November 2021 (version 1.63) update release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_63#_updated-find-actions), they show that the Find actions buttons (`Match Case`, `Match Whole Word`, and `Use Regular Expression`) hover and active states can be styled (the example gif shows blue). They also mention that the style for the buttons in the search view now use the same style as the editor.

[image]

Which properties can I target using `workbench.colorCustomizations` in `settings.json` to change the background color of those buttons when hovering over them, or when they are active (the states which are shown in blue in the example gif)?

I've searched the [Action colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#action-colors), [Button control](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#button-control), and [Input control](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#input-control) sections of the Theme Color documentation but I couldn't find the right properties. `toolbar.hoverBackground` changes the hover color of the Find toolbar's `Previous Match`, `Next Match`, `Find in Selection`, and `Close` buttons, but not the ones inside the Find text field.

I've also tried using `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` in the Command Palette, which is great for identifying theme color property names for code in the editor panel, but it can't be used for the VS Code application UI elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `colorCustomizations` in your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorWidget.foreground": "#f00",
    "icon.foreground": "#f00"   // colors the arrows/close in the Find widget

    "inputOption.activeBorder": "#666",          // active states
    "inputOption.activeBackground": "#777676",
    "inputOption.activeForeground": "#fff",

    "inputOption.hoverBackground": "#ff0000",    // hover state
}
```

From [Editor widget colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-widget-colors).  That is a "Find Widget".

The `"icon.foreground"` setting will also affect the arrows/close icons in the Search View.

And the `inputOption` settings will affect the Search view buttons as well.  I don't think there is any to theme those Find Widget hover/active states without also affecting the Search view buttons hover/active states.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear that I'm trying to change the background color of the buttons inside the Find text field for only the hover and active states (by active I mean the color it changes to after you click on it and move the mouse away). Basically, mine are a shade of gray which is hard to see, and I want to have something more high-contrast, like the blue shown in their example gif. `editorWidget.foreground` does indeed change the button color, but I tried `editorWidget.hoverBackground` but that's not a valid property.

Comment: I added the hover and active states for those buttons.